# Refer to previous edges in PGRouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I would like to write a cost functiont that takes into account the previous edge, rather than only the current one, to calculate for instance:

> ***Route with the smallest number of turns***

For that I would have to check for turns every time, ie. check the difference in angle between my current edge and the previously visited one.

I have seen similar things for `[pgr_trsp][1]` but these seem to totally restrict certain given turns rather than returning an aggregate on the number of turns.

Is there an easy way I am not seeing for calculating this?